# Jenkins 2 pipeline deploying to udeploy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, udeploy

I am creating a CI/CD pipeline. I am trying to create a groovy function in order to deploy a build to udeploy.

I know I will need to pass the parameters used in to the function such as:
udeployServer,
component,
artifactDirectory,
version,
deployApplication,
environment and 
deployProcess.

I was wondering has anyone tried to implement this or has anyone any idea how I should approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about u`deploy servers` but I do know there is [no pipeline plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) for `udeploy`, which means that you will not have a function such as :

```
udeploy: server=yourserver component=yourcomponent artifactDirectory=...
```

However Jenkins allow you to use shell commands inside your `groovy pipeline`, so you should be able to do pretty much everything you need. So I guess the real question is how do you usually deploy a build to `udeploy` ? Do you do it via a REST API, do you push a file via FTP, ... ?

Jenkins build will be pretty straightforward, have a look at how to [checkout and build](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#checking-out-and-building-sources) using Jenkins pipeline.

An example pipeline could look like :

```
{
  stage 'Build'
  def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
  sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean install"

  //... Some other stages as needed...

  stage 'Deploy'
  sh "execute sh deploy script here..."
}
```

... where you deploy stage could use other plugins to copy files to your server, run REST API requests, etc. While writing a pipeline, have a look at `Pipeline Syntax` link for a Snippet Generator giving more detailed information about existing plugins.